# How to make an html form field required ONLY if an option is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have one field where the user must check option A or B. If user checks option A, then a hidden field becomes visible. In the case that user checks option A, I want this now-visible field to be required. The problem is, if I make the hidden field required, there is an error when the user checks option B (the field remains invisible + is still required).

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself.

Comment: The title is the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
A : <input type="radio" name="check" id="check_a"  onclick="check_a()">
<br>
B : <input type="radio"  name="check" id="check_b"  onclick="check_b()">
<div id="hidden_input"></div>
<script>
function check_a() {
    document.getElementById("hidden_input").innerHTML = "<input placeholder='Something required if A is checked' required/>";
}
function check_b() {
    document.getElementById("hidden_input").innerHTML = "<input placeholder='Something required if B is checked' required/>";
}
</script>
```

Edit for downvoters : The person with the question said it's perfect, which means he understands how the code works.

Comment: Dumping code and no explanation what so ever is a really bad answer.

Comment: Anybody with no basic knowledge will understand how the code works and edit it to fit his needs without any explanations :)